# Share azure devops variables across projects

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

I am trying to share linked variables across projects.
I read that is was not possible but I found this API endpoint that may do the trick.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups/share-variable-group?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

When I call this API:
PATCH [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups?variableGroupId={variableGroupId}&api-version=6.0-preview.2](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups?variableGroupId=%7BvariableGroupId%7D&api-version=6.0-preview.2)

with this Body:

```
{
"variableGroupProjectReferences":[
    {
        "description":"test1",
        "name":"test1",
        "projectReference":{
            "id":"50f7c113-de21-4e19-b910-b37ebffa984f",
            "name":"Customer Services"
        }
    }]
}
```

I get this response:

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: variableGroupProjectReferences",
    "typeName": "System.ArgumentNullException, mscorlib",
    "typeKey": "ArgumentNullException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 0
}
```

Comment: The API appears to be broken. According to the documentation, a property named `variableGroupProjectReferences` **shouldn't even be in the body**; the root property should be named `body`. Give a more recent API version a shot; 6.0 is pretty old and it's up to 7.1 now.

Answer (score 1):

> Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: variableGroupProjectReferences

The request body seems to have issue.

You can refer to the following sample:

```
[
    {

    "variableGroupProjectReferences": 
    {
        "projectReference": {
        "id": "ProjectID",
        "name": "ProjectName"
        },
        "name": "variablegroupname",
        "description": ""
        }
 
   }
]
```

But it will show the error: **Sharing of variable group is not allowed.**

The cause of this issue is that the variable group property： `"isShared": false`

You can get the variable group property with the Rest API: [Variablegroups - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)

But currently it seems that we cannot change this property. So we couldn't share the variable group.

Refer to this feedback ticket: [VariableGroup cannot be shared via REST API](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/variablegroup-cannot-be-shared-via-rest-api/488577).

I suggest that you can report the issue to [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=problem).